# deploying multple war files using intelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a maven based spring mvc project. I can build that project and run it via tomcat manually like this

```
mvn package -Dbuild.name=App1
mvn package -Dbuild.name=App2
mvn package -Dbuild.name=App3
```

and then can copy those generate war files App1.war, App2.war and App3.war into my tomcat folder and start it. It works fine.

Question is how to do the same using intelliJ IDEA?

I generated war files one by one by using Maven Project window and creating custom value for package goal. It generates .war files in target folder. But when I run it in Tomcat of intelliJ it only runs the application at root "/" address. For other addresses

```
/App2 -> 404
/App3 -> 404
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have [multiple artifacts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html) created in IntelliJ IDEA and configured for deployment at the same time in the application server Run/Debug configuration, `Deployment` tab under different contexts.

Note that `Deployment` tab has a configuration to perform the deployment from the `External source` where you can specify the location of the war produced by Maven if you don't want to use artifacts for some reason.

Comment: how to combine all -Dbuild.name commands in one? Currently I am creating one command executing it and then modifying it to next command.

Comment: You can create run configurations for the maven goals from the context menu of the goal in the Maven Projects tool window. Specify the parameters for the goal. Then you can set one run configuration to depend on another one in the `Before launch` section. This way running a single configuration for Maven goal will trigger other configurations to run.

Comment: I'd recommend using artifacts instead, this way you can build and deploy them automatically under different contexts.

Comment: I am not able to find different artifacts in Artifact window. Its only showing one artifact there.

Comment: You can add more artifacts manually, note that one artifact can wrap the contents another one.